# C++ basic syntax errors

Tags: c++, definition

I am getting errors with the following code and don't know where I am going wrong.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <cstring>
#include "Translator.h"

using namespace std;

int main (void)

{

char Dictionary::translate (char out_s[], const char s[])
{
int i;

for (i=0;i < numEntries; i++)
{
if (strcmp(englishWord[i], s)==0)
break;
}

if (i<numEntries)
strcpy(out_s,elvishWord[i]);
}

char Translator::toElvish(char elvish_line[],const char english_line[])

{
int j=0;

char temp_eng_words[2000][50];
//char temp_elv_words[2000][50]; NOT SURE IF I NEED THIS

std::string str = english_line;
std::istringstream stm(str);
string word;
while( stm >> word) // read white-space delimited tokens one by one
{
int k=0;
strcpy (temp_eng_words[k],word.c_str());

k++;

}

for (int i=0; i<2000;i++) // ERROR: out_s was not declared in this scope
{
Dictionary::translate (out_s,temp_eng_words[i]); // ERROR RELATES TO THIS LINE
}

}



Translator::Translator(const char dictFileName[]) : dict(dictFileName)
{
char englishWord[2000][50];
char temp_eng_word[50];
char temp_elv_word[50];
char elvishWord[2000][50];
int num_entries;

fstream str;

str.open(dictFileName, ios::in);
int i;

while (!str.fail())
{
for (i=0; i< 2000; i++)
{
str>> temp_eng_word;
str>> temp_elv_word;
strcpy(englishWord[i],temp_eng_word);
strcpy(elvishWord[i],temp_elv_word);
}

num_entries = i;

}

str.close();

}
}}
```

The first error I get is around

```
char Dictionary::translate (char out_s[], const char s[])
 {
   int i;
```

where it says "A function definition is not allowed before a '{' token. The second error I get is at the that there is an expected '}' at the end of input, but no matter how many i put in or leave out it still gives the same error message.

And ideas??

Comment: You can not define a function inside another function. Move the member function declarations outside main.

Comment: `main` is a function; you have all your other functions *inside* `main`.  Functions don't "nest" in C++.

Comment: It'll mess you guys up when the new inline functions are introduced in c++11. :)

Comment: Suggestions:  1. Use `std::string`.  2. Use `std::map`, which is an associative array, a.k.a., dictionary.  This will ease your burden on implementation so you can concentrate on design.

Comment: @Derija93 **Inline** functions exist for ages. **Nested** functions weren't introduced by C++11

Comment: @icepack Well I guess `inline` was the wrong word for this. So is nested. They're called [Lambda Closures](http://www.cprogramming.com/c++11/c++11-lambda-closures.html). Sorry for my bad wording.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're defining all the functions *inside* `main()`. Move them all before `main()`.

Comment: The functions have already been declared in a class inside translator.h

What i am actually trying to do is call  the functions inside the main function, but am unsure how to proceed.

Comment: @DanieloKeeffe Declared (name and parameters only) or defined (along with body)? The normal approach would be: declare them in a header file; define them in a .cpp file; call them in `main()`.

Comment: At present I have a translator.cpp, a main.cpp and a translator.h file. Can the translator.cpp function without an int main, just define the functions which are called with main() in main.cpp?

Comment: @DanieloKeeffe 1) That's precisely how you'd do it. Declare functions in `translator.h`, which is included in both .cpp files. Define them in `translator.cpp` and call them in `main.cpp` - including the header there will make their declarations visible. 2) There must be exactly one `int main()` function in a C++ program, regardless of the number of .cpp files (= "translation units") comprising it.

Answer (score 4):

You shouldn't define a function right within another function.
Function definitions come after each other.

Answer (score 4):

It's not allowed to declare inner functions in `C++`.
Move your functions to a distinct scope, without nesting into `main`.